# Atmosphere on Mars

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, atmospheric-science, density

I am currently building a simulation for the perseverance rover landing on Mars. I need to work out the atmospheric density / pressure at various heights. I looked at Wikipedia and the NASA website and apparently there are different models. How do I work out the pressure at a given altitude and how will this vary due to temperature? Does the pressure determine the temperature, if so how can I work out the pressure on a hot day?

[image: Mars atmospheric model]

[image: Barometric equation]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation you need to work with is the same as the one from hydrostatics, except for a gas:  $$\frac{dp}{dz}=-\rho g$$where $\rho$ is the gas density and g is the gravitational constant (on Mars).  From the ideal gas law, we also have $$\rho=\frac{pM}{RT}$$where M is the average molar mass of the gas, R is the universal gas constant, and T is the absolute temperature.  So, combining these equations, you have $$\frac{1}{p}\frac{dp}{dz}=-\frac{Mg}{RT(z)}$$  So, if you know the temperature as a function of elevation z and the pressure at ground level, you can integrate this equation to get the pressure at any other elevation z.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I am a secondary student at the moment so a lot of these concepts are new to me! I am confused as how I would find the temperature as a function of height? Would I revert back to the earlier equations, then integrate wrt dz taking -Mg/R as a constant?

Comment: Yes, but the temperature vs elevation needs to be known experimentally.  You would integrate the equations they gave you for temperature (presumably obtained experimentally), the way that you indicated.

Comment: Ok, I think from looking at the formula people tend to use T(z) = T0 - Az where T0 and A are constants. I presume if I wanted to model a hot day I would increase T0 or for humid air I would change A or even the function.

Comment: The equation applies on average over the entire atmosphere, and local variations in temperature generate air flows, and the effects of these air flows on the pressure distribution.  That's how weather models operate.  The best you can do with this approach is to get the global average pressure distribution.  To account for local temperature variations, you need a detailed meteorology model.  Also, at least on earth, the linear temperature distribution is a decent approximation only in the troposphere (below 10 km).  See the US Standard Atmosphere model for more details.

Comment: So I'm guessing this is why NASA recommended the segmented model for altitudes above or below 7000m. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, at least on earth, the temperature in the stratosphere rises with altitude